# C++ - map.insert(make_pair()) doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


int main() {
    std::map<std::string,int> m;
    int a,b,c;
    std::string d;
    std::cin >> a;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        std::cin >> b;
        std::cin >> d;
        std::cin >> c;
        if (b == 1) {
            std::cout << 1 << "\n";
            if (m[d] == 0){
                std::cout << "md==0\n";
                m.insert(std::make_pair(d, c)); // Line 23
                std::cout << d << " " << c << " " << m[d] << " Inserted\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Uvelich\n";
                m[d] += c;
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that line 23 doesn't affect m variable. But when I run func explicitly it works fine.

```
int main()
{
    map<string,int> m;
    m.insert(make_pair("t", 1));
    cout<<m["t"];
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to launch make_pair with fixed value, but nonetheless.
I expect it to work in a usual way, just insert a pair.

BTW, it is a task from Hackerrank, Maps-STL (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-maps/problem?isFullScreen=true)

Comment: All question related code required to produce your problem(s) should be provided [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74960211/edit) as a properly formatted [mcve].

Comment: We require all code to be in the question as text, not links.

Comment: Operator `[]` inserts the element to the map if it wasn't there before. You call it before insertion, so the element always exists before insertion and isn't inserted again.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `m[d]` already inserts default element in map,
so next `m.insert(make_pair(d, c));` does nothing.

```
if(m[d]==0){
    cout<<"md==0\n";
    m.insert(make_pair(d, c));
    cout<<d <<" "<<c<<" "<<m[d]<<" Inserted\n";
} else {
    cout<<"Uvelich\n";
    m[d] += c;
}
```

could be (with debug print removed)

```
m[d] += c;
```